# Is 60 minutes enough for connecting in Dusseldorf?

Tags: transit, short-connections, dus, eurowings

On 1st November, I will have my first flight connection (ever, actually) in Dusseldorf, for this reason I am quite stressed about it and I would like to ask some questions. I will travel with an hand luggage that I will bring in the cabin and I am an EU (italian) citizen. My flight is on **a single booking**, with Eurowings.

- EW9827 09:15 Milan Malpensa - 10:50 Dusseldorf
- 60 minutes connection
- EW9732 11:50 Dusseldorf - 13:40 Krakow

I would like to ask how transferring in Dusseldorf work - I read a lot of topics about this but I would like to ask again (flight may be in the same Terminal or in different ones, it seems it would be A or B). It seems it is very easy after you get off bus/plane, but I would love to hear from someone. Since I will go from Schengen to Schengen flight, I guess I won't have a passport check (and also security check?) while transferring and I can go directly to the next gate? Is it enough time?

Since the booking is made with a single ticket, will Eurowings somehow "wait" for me if there will be a short delay? Or will I have some sort of protection? I booked a ticket with the SMART fare but I can't read anything about this specifically.

Comment: In general, because your flights are on a single ticket, once you board the first leg, the rest is essentially out of your hands.  The airline may expedite your passage through the airport in Düsseldorf, but regardless if you miss the flight they will have to rebook you on the next available flight, offer meals and accommodations if the delay requires them, and possibly offer compensation under EU air passenger protections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just there 3 weeks ago and had no issues connecting to my flight to Napoli. The 3 terminals are connected and you can get from one to the other quite easily. Since you only have a hand luggage and an EU citizen, 60 min is more than enough. Since it's on a single ticket, they know you're coming to and connecting to a flight, so do not worry.

Comment: This is a reassuring thing to read. Did you have to go to another terminal in order to take your connecting flight? If yes, did you have any ID or security checks?